# x509 Certificate signed by unknown authority - kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, x509, kubelet

I search the previews post for this but I can't find the solution, sorry.

I install metrics server on kubeadm v1.12 and I get this error from the logs:

1 master node and 1 slave node, in private network.

```
Get https://ip-10-0-1-154:10250/stats/summary/: x509: a certificate signed by an unknown authority, unable to fully scrape metrics from source
```

I don't install any certificate.

How can I install a new certificate and where I need to change this without set up a new kubernetes cluster?

Sorry for the noob question, I tried to create a new certificate but I cannot make kubelet to change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a problem with kubeadm in where it generates the `kubelet` certificates on the nodes under `/var/lib/kubelet/pki` (`kubelet.crt`,`kubelet.key`) signed by a different CA from the one used for the master(s) under `/etc/kubernetes/pki` (ca.crt). Some background [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server/issues/130)
.
You'll have to regenerate the certificates for your kubelets signed by the CA on the master(s) `/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt`

You can follow something like [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/certificates/). For example use [`cfssl`](https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl)

Something like this:

```
$ mkdir ~/mycerts; cd ~/mycerts
$ cp /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt ca.pem
$ cp /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key ca-key.pem
```

Create a file `kubelet-csr.json` with something like this:

```
{
  "CN": "kubernetes",
  "hosts": [
    "127.0.0.1",
    "<your-node-name>",
    "kubernetes",
    "kubernetes.default",
    "kubernetes.default.svc",
    "kubernetes.default.svc.cluster",
    "kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local"
  ],
  "key": {
    "algo": "rsa",
    "size": 2048
  },
  "names": [{
    "C": "US",
    "ST": "NY",
    "L": "City",
    "O": "Org",
    "OU": "Unit"
  }]
}
```

Create a `ca-config.json` file:

```
{
  "signing": {
    "default": {
      "expiry": "8760h"
    },
    "profiles": {
      "kubernetes": {
        "usages": [
          "signing",
          "key encipherment",
          "server auth",
          "client auth"
        ],
        "expiry": "8760h"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Create a `config.json` file:

```
{
    "signing": {
        "default": {
            "expiry": "168h"
        },
        "profiles": {
            "www": {
                "expiry": "8760h",
                "usages": [
                    "signing",
                    "key encipherment",
                    "server auth"
                ]
            },
            "client": {
                "expiry": "8760h",
                "usages": [
                    "signing",
                    "key encipherment",
                    "client auth"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Generate the certs:

```
$ cfssl gencert -ca=ca.pem -ca-key=ca-key.pem \
  --config=ca-config.json -profile=kubernetes \
  kubelet-csr.json | cfssljson -bare kubelet
```

Copy the files to your nodes:

```
$ scp kubelet.pem <node-ip>:/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt
$ scp kubelet-key.pem <node-ip>:/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.key
```

Restart the kubelet on your node:

```
$ systemctl restart kubelet
```

PD. Opened [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1223) to track the issue.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble :) . I tried with your way i get this error: {"code":2003,"message":"Failed to parse private key"}
Failed to parse input: unexpected end of JSON input.

I tried with Cloudflare tutorial still the same error from the start:
x509: a certificate signed by an unknown authority

Comment: It have same error whats why :) 
$ cp /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt ca-key.pem is the cert not the key thanks a lot :) :P

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: If you're here for an installation with kind --kubeconfig=.. don't use this parameter, the issue comes from using a wrong user certificate. Export a new kubeconfig before

Comment: @tuxErrante what do you mean by dont use --kubeconfig ? I'm rotating my cluster CA, but the certs generated in kubelet.conf fails with the x509 error above. THis is a kind cluster.

Comment: I resolved doing an export KUBECONFIG=,bla/bla, before every kubectl